# merge three models and filter them out by id in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

I faced such a problem: I have a Home page where I show all kinds of drinks in the menu and I want to create a page where the user clicks and get a filtered list, where drinks are already divided into hot and cold according to their ID. I know that the method `where` is used to filter by ID. But my problem is that I have not just two models which have the same id's in them, but plus another two models through which I have to filter the values and get the already filtered values from the **FilterMenu** model. I don't know how to solve this problem correctly. Please, help me, if you can.

Also addition: all models are entitled by each other by their id's, so **DessertId** is bond with **DrinksId** by `mv_id` and **DrinksId** is bonded with **FilterMenu** by **sId**.

I thought about combining all these models together and then filtering, but I don't know how to do it correctly. Is it necessary to merge all the models here?

My models:

```
class DessertsId {
  final int mvId;
  final int mrId;

  DessertsId({this.mvId, this.mrId});
}

class DrinksId{
  final int mvId;
  final int sId;
  DrinksId({this.mvId, this.sId});
}
```

**from this models i want to get all filtrated items through the previous 2**

```
class FilterMenu{
  final String mTitle;
  final int sId;
  FilterMenu({this.mTitle, this.sId});
}
```

**My first page where user taps and go to the filterted Page:**

```
class Home extends StatelessWidget {
   Home({Key key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  List<CommonMenu> common = <CommonMenu>[
    CommonMenu(commonTitle: 'Hot Drinks', mrId: 2),
    CommonMenu(commonTitle: 'Cold Drinks', mrId: 1),
  ];
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(),
      body: ListView.builder(
        itemCount: common.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index){
        return ListTile(
          title: Text(common[index].commonTitle),
          onTap: () {
            Navigator.push(context,
                MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => Menu(

                )));
          },
        );
      }),
    );
  }
}
```

**My second page where should be all filtered items store:**

```
class Menu extends StatefulWidget {
  final int sId;

  const Menu({Key key, this.sId}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  _MenuState createState() => _MenuState();
}

class _MenuState extends State<Menu> {
  List<DessertsId> desert = <DessertsId>[
    DessertsId(mvId: 1, mrId: 1),
    DessertsId(mvId: 2, mrId: 2),
    DessertsId(mvId: 1, mrId: 1),
    DessertsId(mvId: 2, mrId: 2),
    DessertsId(mvId: 2, mrId: 2),
  ];

  List<DrinksId> drinks = <DrinksId>[
    DrinksId(mvId: 1, sId: 1),
    DrinksId(mvId: 2, sId: 2),
    DrinksId(mvId: 1, sId: 1),
    DrinksId(mvId: 2, sId: 2),
    DrinksId(mvId: 1, sId: 1),
    DrinksId(mvId: 2, sId: 2),
  ];

  List<FilterMenu> filterMenu = <FilterMenu>[
    FilterMenu(mTitle: 'capuchino', sId: 1),
    FilterMenu(mTitle: 'americano', sId: 2),
    FilterMenu(mTitle: 'latte', sId: 1),
    FilterMenu(mTitle: 'tonic', sId: 2),
    FilterMenu(mTitle: 'ice latte', sId: 1),
    FilterMenu(mTitle: 'frapuchino', sId: 2),
  ];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context)  {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: ListView.builder(
          itemCount: filterMenu.length,
          itemBuilder: (context, index) {
            return ListTile(
              title: Text(filterMenu[index].mTitle),
            );
          },
        ));
  }
}
```

**This is the code I try to filtrate and combined models:**

```
Iterable<CommonItems> merged(List <DessertsId> desert,
        List <DrinksId> drinks, List <FilterMenu> filterMenu) sync* {
      for (var i = 0; i < filterMenu.length; i++) {
        var desertes = desert.where((element) => element.mrId == filterMenu[i].sId).toList();
        var drink = drinks.where((element) => element.sId == filterMenu[i].sId).toList();
        yield CommonItems(
          desert: desertes,
          drinks: drink,
          mrId: filterMenu[i].sId,
          sId: filterMenu[i].sId
        );
      }
    }
    List<CommonItems> common = merged(desert, drinks, filterMenu).toList();

class CommonItems{
  final int sId;
  final int mrId;
 final List<DessertsId> desert;
  final List<DrinksId> drinks;
  List<FilterMenu> filterMenu;
  final List <CommonMenu> menu;

  CommonItems({this.desert, this.drinks, this.menu, this.sId, this.mrId});
}
```

The screenshots:

[image: first page]

[image: second page with filtered items]

Comment: The DessertsId and DrinksId classes are the same, it would be easier to use enum for different products or types when you want to filter them later.

Comment: Can't you manage the types of the models by adding a new attribute 'type' instead of relying in the ids?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

// Try Something like that:

```
Iterable<CommonItems> merged(List <DessertsId> desert,
    List <DrinksId> drinks, List <FilterMenu> filterMenu) sync* {
  for (var i = 0; i < filterMenu.length; i++) {
    var drink = [];
    var desertes = [];
    for(int j = 0; j< drinks.length;j++){
      if(drinks[j].sId==filterMenu[i].sId) {
        drink.add(drinks[j]);
        for (int k = 0; k < desert.length; k++) {
          if (desert[k].mvId == drinks[j].mvId) {
            desertes.add(desert[k]);
          }
        }
      }
    }

    yield CommonItems(
        desert: desertes,
        drinks: drink,
        mrId: filterMenu[i].sId,
        sId: filterMenu[i].sId
    );
  }
}
List<CommonItems> common = merged(desert, drinks, filterMenu).toList();
```

Comment: Hi @Habib ur Rehman Thanks for your help. I am trying you code above and now get this error type `List<dynamic>' is not a subtype of type 'List<DrinksId>`  . I searched for an answer and as I understand I missed method toList() in my code, but it seems everything perfectly fine to me. Am I missing something?

Comment: try List<DrinksId> drink = []; List <DessertsId> desertes = [];  
instead of "var drink = []; var desertes = [];" and it will be ok

Comment: I accept the answer above bacause in this specific question it will be work fine, but I want you to warn that if you put another for-loop inside, things get slower.